# Clear WooCommerce checkout pre-filled shipping fields values

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, field, checkout

I need to clear shipping fields from a wordpress customer profile after they have placed an order

The shop is set up to sell giftbaskets and many returning customers will want to send a giftbasket to a different shipping address each time they return. They will use the same billing info that is in their profile

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields','custom_override_checkout_fields' );

function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

  $fields['shipping']['shipping_first_name'] = '';
  $fields['shipping']['shipping_last_name'] = '';
  $fields['shipping']['shipping_company'] = '';
  $fields['shipping']['shipping_address_1'] = '';
  $fields['shipping']['shipping_address_2'] = '';
  $fields['shipping']['shipping_city'] = '';
  $fields['shipping']['shipping_postcode'] = '';
  $fields['shipping']['shipping_country'] = '';
  $fields['shipping']['shipping_state'] = '';

  return $fields;
}
```

This clears the fields and it also clears the field labels. Can I edit the existing to to clear just the fields and leave the labels visible above each field.

Thanks alot for looking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the right filter hook… The following will clear pre-filled shipping fields values:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_get_value', 'clear_shipping_fields_values', 5, 2 );
function clear_shipping_fields_values( $value, $input ) {
    $keys = ['first_name','last_name','company','address_1','address_2','city','postcode','country','state'];
    $key  = str_replace('shipping_', '', $input);
    if( in_array($key, $keys) && is_checkout() ) {
        $value = '';
    }
    return $value;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

Comment: That's awesome it worked, even for custom shipping fields like 'add a gift message'.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.